# Base64 to application/octet-stream

Tags: encoding, base64

This will sound very naive but I need to find a very quick way to decode a base64 encoded file to a binary file specifically the content-type to octet-stream file. A linux command or something similar will do the trick. I have googled and searched internally in Stack Overflow for this but can't seem to find anything concrete.

Comment: [base64 not working for you?](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)

Comment: No. The application expects the file to be binary encoded(the actual binary file has a size ~11MB while the base 64 encoded file has a size of ~15MB)

Comment: Yes, you can do that with what I linked `$ base64 -d base64encodedfile > binaryfile`